# Multiply an integer in a list by a word in the list

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to multiply a number following a string by the string. I want to find the RMM of a compound so I started by making a dictionary of RMMs then have them added together. My issue is with compounds such as H2O.

```
name = input("Insert the name of a molecule/atom to find its RMM/RAM: ")
compound = re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', name)
Compound = compound.split(' ')
r = re.split('(\d+)', compound)
```

For example:

```
When name = H2O
Compound = ['', 'H2', 'O']
r = ['H', '2', 'O']
```

I want to multiply 2 by H making a value "['H', 'H', 'O']."

TLDR: I want integers following names in a list to print the previously listed object 'x' amount of times (e.g. [O, 2] => O O, [C, O, 2] => C O O)

The question is somewhat complicated, so let me know if I can clarify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following, after you define `compound`:

```
test = re.findall('([a-zA-z]+)(\d*)', compound)
expand = [a*int(b) if len(b) > 0 else a for (a, b) in test]
```

Match on letters of 1 or more instances followed by an optional number of digits - if there's no digit we just return the letters, if there is a digit we duplicate the letters by the appropriate value. This doesn't quite return what you expected - it instead will return `['HH', 'O']` - so please let me know if this suits.

EDIT: assuming your compounds use elements consisting of either a single capital letter or a single capital followed by a number of lowercase letters, you can add the following:

```
final = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', ''.join(expand))
```

Which will return your elements each as a separate entry in the list, e.g. `['H', 'H', 'O']`

EDIT 2: with the assumption of my previous edit, we can actually reduce the whole thing down to just a couple of lines:

```
name = raw_input("Insert the name of a molecule/atom to find its RMM/RAM: ")
test = re.findall('([A-z][a-z]*)(\d*)', name)
final = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', ''.join([a*int(b) if len(b) > 0 else a for (a, b) in test]))
```

Comment: You can always flatten the resulting list using something like  `[char for charGroup in ['HH', 'O'] for char in charGroup]` which outputs `['H', 'H', 'O']`

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do something like...

```
compound = 'h2o' 
final = []
for x in range(len(compound)):
    if compound[x].isdigit() and x != 0:
        for count in range(int(compound[x])-1):
            final.append(compound[x-1])
    else:
       final.append(compound[x])
```

Comment: `compound[x] != '0'` check is redundant. Also for a bad input `final.append(compund[x-1])` will raise exception

Comment: You're right. Changed to x != 0- that should eliminate the bad input potential as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex and a generator function:

```
import re

def multilpy_string(seq):
    regex = re.compile("([a-zA-Z][0-9])|([a-zA-Z])")
    for alnum, alpha in regex.findall(''.join(seq)):
        if alnum:
            for char in alnum[0] * int(alnum[1]):
                yield char
        else:
            yield alpha

l = ['C', 'O', '2'] # ['C', 'O', 'O']
print(list(multilpy_string(l)))
```

We join your list back together using `''.join`. Then we compile a regex pattern that matches two types of strings in your list. If the string is a letter and is followed by a number its put in a group. If its a single number, its put in its own group. We then iterate over each group. If we've found something in a group, we  yield the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few nested for comprehensions to get it done in two lines:

```
In [1]: groups = [h*int(''.join(t)) if len(t) else h for h, *t in re.findall('[A-Z]\d*', 'H2O')]

In[2]: [c for cG in groups for c in cG]
Out[2]: ['H', 'H', 'O']
```

Note: I am deconstructing and reconstructing strings so this is probably not the most efficient method.

Here is a longer example:

```
In [2]: def findElements(molecule):
    ...:      groups = [h*int(''.join(t)) if len(t) else h for h, *t in re.findall('[A-Z]\d*', molecule)]
    ...:      return [c for cG in groups for c in cG]

In [3]: findElements("H2O5S7D")
Out[3]: ['H', 'H', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'D']
```

Comment: You're assuming elements consisting solely of capital letters and (I think) that Python 3 is being used.

Comment: Yep, only capitals but a quick `[A-Z][a-z]?` would fix that. I would update but your answer is superior anyway (with the unpacking of the groups as a tuple rather than my head/tail matching).

Answer (score -1):

In python3 (I don't know about python2) you can simply multiply strings.

for example:

```
print("H"*2) # HH
print(2*"H") # HH
```

Proof that this information is useful:

```
r = ['H', '2', 'O']
replacements = [(index, int(ch)) for index, ch in enumerate(r) if ch.isdigit()]

for postion, times in replacements:
    r[postion] = (times - 1) * r[postion - 1]

# flaten the result
r = [ch for s in r for ch in s]

print(r) # ['H', 'H', 'O']
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question. You may want to read over it again to get a better understanding of what Gad is asking.

Comment: Wow, an downvote within less than 30sec after my post. I am impressed by your fast ability of a judgment ;-)

Comment: and its not a direct answer, but it is useful in my option

(This should appear in the same comment within a new line - but pressing enter posted it instead of making a new line, sorry for that)

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way :) I think you simply misunderstood the question. And, as I said in my previous comment, just read over the question again to see where you went wrong. Cheers!

Comment: In my opinion answers don't have to give a complete solution (I am always happy about some tips and maybe new knowledge! :) )

But I added a complete solution for you as proof, that my answer is useful ;) (I have understood the question the first time; maybe you should have though over my answer a little bit more, before deciding to downvote and write why you downvoted within max 30secs ;P )

Comment: Down votes are anonymous, So you cannot know for sure who down voted your answer. But I will say that I down voted your answer this time. I believe it is important to provide clarity sometimes for why you down vote something.